# Multiple processes writing to same file throws Permission denied error

Tags: python, locking, nfs

I am observing a weird behavior in my python script. My script takes a lock on a common file and then writes it. There are 100s of these processes running at a given moment. Transiently, I am observing permission denied error from the code from some of the processes.

I am running all processes on linux and nfs file system. I am using a wrapper over fcntl lock, which I cannot share due to confidentiality clause.

I want to know if anyone has faced similar issue on linux/nfs in python?

Comment: Show us the code that obtains and releases the lock.

Comment: May be you can share a demo code snippet to debug the issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `fcntl()` man page says it returns "permission denied" (`EACCES`) for "Operation is prohibited by locks held by other processes", so it sounds like you're not handling the locking correctly.